# segmentation fault 'gsl_spmatrix_add'

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gsl

EDIT:
I have changed the question to new code that produces the same error and is more reliable in doing so.

I have been struggling to find a segmentation fault in my code for a while now and have boiled it down to the following code:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_spmatrix.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test_gsl() {
    size_t size = 5;
    size_t nzmax = 5 * 5;
    constexpr size_t threads = 5;

    // allocate
    gsl_spmatrix* thread_matrices[threads];
    for (size_t thread = 0; thread < threads; thread++) {
        thread_matrices[thread] = gsl_spmatrix_alloc_nzmax(size, size, nzmax, GSL_SPMATRIX_TRIPLET);
    }

    // set
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        gsl_spmatrix_set(thread_matrices[i], 0, 0, 1.0);
    }

    // crs
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        gsl_spmatrix* temp = thread_matrices[i];
        thread_matrices[i] = gsl_spmatrix_crs(thread_matrices[i]);
        gsl_spmatrix_free(temp);
    }

    // add to total
    gsl_spmatrix* total_matrix = gsl_spmatrix_alloc_nzmax(size, size, nzmax, GSL_SPMATRIX_CRS);
    gsl_spmatrix* total_copy = gsl_spmatrix_alloc_nzmax(size, size, nzmax, GSL_SPMATRIX_CRS);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        gsl_spmatrix_memcpy(total_copy, total_matrix);  // this is required to avoid another segfault
        gsl_spmatrix_add(total_matrix, total_copy, thread_matrices[i]); // unknown segfault!
    }

    gsl_spmatrix_free(total_matrix);
    gsl_spmatrix_free(total_copy);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    
    test_gsl();
    printf("end\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this I consistently get the following output:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The segmentation fault is on the line with `gsl_spmatrix_add(total_matrix, total_copy, thread_matrices[i]);`.

I'm compiling this code using cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

project(diskmodel)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)

add_subdirectory("src")
```

```
project(galaxy)

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}" SUFFIX ".exe")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} GSL::gsl GSL::gslcblas )
```

**What is causing this seg fault?**

EDIT:

After compiling with:
`g++ 'gsl-config --libs' main.cpp -fsanitize=undefined -g` I get the same output as before. When compiling with `address` I get:

```
=================================================================
==31330==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 400 byte(s) in 5 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7efd44b64a06 in __interceptor_calloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:153
    #1 0x7efd449d393e in gsl_spmatrix_alloc_nzmax (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.23+0x1f893e)

Indirect leak of 240 byte(s) in 5 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7efd44b64808 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x7efd449d3b6c in gsl_spmatrix_alloc_nzmax (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.23+0x1f8b6c)

Indirect leak of 200 byte(s) in 5 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7efd44b64808 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x7efd449d3b88 in gsl_spmatrix_alloc_nzmax (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.23+0x1f8b88)

Indirect leak of 40 byte(s) in 5 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7efd44b64808 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x7efd449d39ac in gsl_spmatrix_alloc_nzmax (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.23+0x1f89ac)

Indirect leak of 40 byte(s) in 5 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7efd44b64808 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x7efd449d397d in gsl_spmatrix_alloc_nzmax (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.23+0x1f897d)
```

When compiling using my cmake file and running `gdb galaxy.exe` I get the following backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7f2c185 in gsl_spblas_scatter () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.23
#1  0x00007ffff7f2b364 in gsl_spmatrix_add () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.23
#2  0x00005555555553d2 in test_gsl () at .../src/main.cpp:35
#3  0x0000555555555420 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdaf8) at .../src/main.cpp:44
```

and no history when using `-p`.

When using `ulimit -c unlimited` and then running a core file is not generated. I tried looking into this, but I can't seem to find it to generate anywhere and I don't know why.

Comment: On my computer (Manjaro Linux, gcc 11) there's no segfault. I've run the code with undefined and address sanitizers, they found no errors.

Comment: Alright thanks, any idea what could be the cause for a segfault on my end?

Comment: Which OS do you use? Do you know how to inspect a core dump? How to use   a sanitizer? The easiest way for you would be to run the program under a debugger  and see there what causes the problem.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 20.04. I used VS code to debug this code and when it got to the line with ´gsl_spmatrix_add` it gave a segfault. That's all I know really.

Comment: 1. compile `g++ \`gsl-config --libs\` main.cpp -fsanitize=undefined -g` where `main.cpp` is your minimal example. Run. See the report. 2. use  `-fsanitize=address` instead of `-fsanitize=undefined`, rerun the program, see the report.

Comment: 3. Compile with `-g`.  Run, from a console,  `gdb ./a.out`, where `./a.out` is the name of your executable. Inside `gdb`, press `r`. It should run the program and stop exactly at the instruction that causes segafault. Inspect the state of the program. Most useuful commands: `l`, `bt`, `p`.

Comment: 4. Compile your program with `-g`. In the console, if you use bash, run `ulimit -c unlimited`. Then run your program. Once it has crashed, you should see a file named `core` or similar. Now run your debugger `gdb ./a.out core`, where `./a.out` is your executable and `core` is the core file. This will invoke the debugger that will load your program just at the state  before it crashed. Inspect it using your favorite gdb commands, see item 3. `core` contains the memory dump of the program at the moment of crash.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I have tried what you said and edited the question to contain it.

Comment: I can see you've simplified `CMakelists.txt`. Have you changed the code, too? Anyway, now I can confirm the segfault precisely at the location you're pointing at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in GSL. Please report :-)

The line

```
gsl_spmatrix *total_matrix = gsl_spmatrix_alloc_nzmax(size, size, nzmax, GSL_SPMATRIX_CRS);
```

is a valid allocator of a GSL sparse matrix. Its initialization, however, is "smart" in that some of its memory buffers are `malloc`ed, but not initialized. This refers to the member `p`.
Line 130 of `init_source.c` (from GSL sources, submodule (directory) `spmatrix`):

```
m->p = malloc((n1 + 1) * sizeof(int));
```

The next thing your code does is

```
gsl_spmatrix_memcpy(total_copy, total_matrix); // this is required to avoid another segfault
```

Well, the comment is somewhat intriguing, but let's look into the code (lines 93-96 of `copy_source.c`):

```
          for (n = 0; n < src->size1 + 1; ++n)
            {
              dest->p[n] = src->p[n];
            }
```

Here, `size1` seems to be the number of matrix rows, which were declared as 5. So, the code replaces (by copying) rubbish with rubbish. This tells us that GSL does not seem to work well if a matrix declared as having 5 rows  has fewer than 5 nonzero rows. I believe this is the solution of your problem. You declared some matrices, e.g. `total_matrix` and `total_copy` as having 5 rows, but they actually have none. So far the code is not buggy, however, because copying rubbish onto rubbish is no error.

The next step in your code:

```
gsl_spmatrix_add(total_matrix, total_copy, thread_matrices[i]);
```

invokes this code related to the member `p`:

```
      for (j = 0; j < outer_size; ++j)
        {
          Cp[j] = nz;
```

This opens a loop, which in your case will be executed 5 times. Here `Cp` is a shorthand for `C->p`. The only element of the `p` member that is initialized so far is thus the j-th one of `C` in  `C = A + B`. Next, inside this loop we can see:

```
          /* CSC: x += A(:,j); CSR: x += A(j,:) */
          nz = FUNCTION (spmatrix, scatter) (a, j, w, x, (int) (j + 1), c, nz);
```

Notice that `j` is passed as the 2nd argument, and incompletely initialised `a` as the 1st. This invokes `spmatrix_scatter` defined in line 538 via a macro.

```
static size_t
FUNCTION (spmatrix, scatter) (const TYPE (gsl_spmatrix) * A, const size_t j, int * w,
                              ATOMIC * x, const int mark, TYPE (gsl_spmatrix) * C, size_t nz)
{
  int p;
  int * Ai = A->i;
  int * Ap = A->p;
  ATOMIC * Ad = A->data;
  int * Ci = C->i;

  for (p = Ap[j]; p < Ap[j + 1]; ++p)
    {
```

Now, as can be seen, GSL accesses an uninitialized values of `Ap[j]` and `Ap[j + 1]`. This results in an immediate segfault a few instructions later.

Now, how to avoid this?

Let's look inside the "kosher" way of creating a CSR matrix (lines 152-156, `compress_source.c`):

```
      Cp = dest->p;

      /* initialize row pointers to 0 */
      for (n = 0; n < dest->size1 + 1; ++n)
        Cp[n] = 0;
```

Hurray! This is a proper initialization of the `p` member. By the way, the next few lines explain that the `p` member in CRS representation is used to store the number of elements in each row. It seems that this is the code missing in `gsl_spmatrix_alloc_nzmax`.

Conclusion: do not rely on matrices returned by `gsl_spmatrix_alloc_nzmax`. They should be OK to use as "destination matrices", e.g. as `C` in `C = A + B`, but not as zero-filled source ones.

Hope this helps.

PS.
You can remove this completely unnecessary invocation of  `gsl_spmatrix_memcpy(total_copy, total_matrix);`

Comment: The line with `gsl_spmatrix_memcpy(total_copy, total_matrix);` was there because if I did `gsl_spmatrix_memcpy(total_matrix, total_matrix);` it would cause a segfault. But that's probably, as you've just explained, because the `total_matrix` shouldn't be used like that if it has been initialised with `gsl_spmatrix_alloc_nzmax`.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by the 'kosher' way of creating a CSR matrix? Do you mean using something like `gsl_spmatrix_csr(dest, src)` or `gsl_spmatrix_compress(src, sptype)`?

Comment: `gsl_spmatrix_crs` looks OK, but I've never used this part of GSL. It's very fortunate  I happen to know what various sparse matrix formats are, but I don't want to go into details of the GSL implementation - it would require too much time & effort.